# Batch Script: to remove a specific/targeted words that include special characters from multiple filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have few mp3 files that have external site names say www.mymusic.com and that name will be either at the start/end of the mp3 file

Examples:

- 01 - {www.mymusic.com} Hello Hello.mp3,
- 02 - {www.mymusic.com} Hai Hai.mp3,
- 03 - Hello Boys [www.musicworld.in].mp3,
- 04 - Hello girls [www.musicworld.in].mp3

So I want a (windows) batch script which asks me to enter a name with special characters say "[www.musicworld.in]" and removes it from multiple mp3 files present in a directory.

Also give me an example how to use/run the code.

Please help :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If any question, that did **not**  `demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved` is closed, we could go home.

Comment: Too true. I'd put on my lawyer-hat and say that OP has demonstrated a quite adequate understanding of the problem to be solved AND has given a reasonable description of how the desired solution should work. What happens when OP has no clue of how to approach a problem and hence cannot provide a 'what I did' or 'why what I did didn't work'? The `tell us...` is a suggestion of what would be useful in solving the actual problem (bolded in the close-reason description)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works immediately!

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /p "word=enter word to remove: "
IF "%word%"=="" GOTO :EOF
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /b "*%word%*.mp3"') DO (
    SET "fname=%%~na"
    SET "fname=!fname:%word%=!"
    IF NOT "!fname!"=="" REN "%%~a" "!fname!%%~xa"
)
```

Comment: ..or it might if you were to use `.mp3`, not `.mp2`... :) Now suppose you were to use `"*%word%*.mp3"` - that would allow you to dispose of the first `if` test...

Comment: Hmm, it's early in the morning here, coffee **not** ready ....:)  Thanks!

Comment: Too much blood in the caffeine-stream. Too common...

Comment: This code is simple and works better. Thanks a lot friend. It answers my problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a batch file that can help you - it uses a helper batch file called repl.bat from http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

At the moment it only echos the REN command so remove `echo` if you are happy with the result.  One benefit with this is that `!` characters are not an issue as they are with delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
set /p "var=Enter the text to remove: "
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.mp3 /b /a-d ^|repl "^(.*)%var%(.*)" "ren \x22$&\x22 \x22$1$2\x22" x ') do echo %%a
```

Comment: Hi Friend, The above code provided by Endoro answers my question simply.. no need of an extra file. May be your code works in complex case? Anyways thanks for responding :)

Comment: That's ok.  I assumed your music files will have `!` in the filenames which this handles.  There are many ways to get around it.